# C# - ActiveX .DrawToBitmap equivalent

Tags: c#, activex

*Short Question:*

How can I draw a copy of a hidden ActiveX control to a Bitmap?

*Longer Question:*

I have an ActiveX control which displays an Image. I would like to hide it behind something (example a panel), copy the display to a Bitmap so as to be able to process it (example access the pixels etc).

Comment: Is the ActiveX from a third party?  If so calling out whose it is could help.

Comment: It is a bespoke ActiveX.

Comment: for a better hide create an invisible iFrame, add the activex to the new invisible iframe. I guess you will have more options to do afterwards(like printing the frame to a file?).

Answer (score 3):

the trick is that you should use `WM_PAINT`

```
    [Flags]
    private enum DrawingOptions
    {
        PRF_CHECKVISIBLE = 0x00000001,
        PRF_NONCLIENT = 0x00000002,
        PRF_CLIENT = 0x00000004,
        PRF_ERASEBKGND = 0x00000008,
        PRF_CHILDREN = 0x00000010,
        PRF_OWNED = 0x00000020
    }

    private const uint WM_PAINT = 0xF;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr dc, DrawingOptions opts);

    private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(axChartSpace1.Width, axChartSpace1.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
            {
                IntPtr dc = g.GetHdc();
                try
                {
                    SendMessage(axChartSpace1.Handle, WM_PRINT, dc,
                    DrawingOptions.PRF_CLIENT |
                    DrawingOptions.PRF_NONCLIENT |
                    DrawingOptions.PRF_CHILDREN);
                }
                finally
                {
                    g.ReleaseHdc();
                }
                bm.Save(@"C:\1.bmp");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's an ActiveX – it does not have a .DrawToBitmap.

Comment: You must have embedded the activeX somewhere. Maybe a .NET control?

Comment: @Mark Anthony all activex controls are wrapped into .net controls if you are using them in WinForms

Comment: Thanks to both for your comments.

Comment: @Andrey in the remarks section of the Control.DrawToBitmap Method page it says "The DrawToBitmap method is not supported for ActiveX controls". Also Intellisense does not show a .DrawToBitmap method.

Comment: @Both Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mark Anthony. i used it with ActiveX controls.

Comment: @Andrey Could it be that the .DrawToBitmap you used was defined in the ActiveX control itself? Intellisense does not show a .DrawToBitmap method for the ActiveX I'm using.

Comment: @Mark Anthony every control that you can drop on form derives from `Control`. May be you forgot to say something about it?

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for your help. I had a look at AxHost and it seems that there is a .DrawToBitmap method but it has [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)] and a comment of “This method is not supported by this control”. That it why it does not show in Intellisense. I tried to use the method just the same and it does not draw the ActiveX control to bitmap because it uses the WM_PRINT, which this ActiveX does not seem to support. Thanks one again for your help.